# Standalone Spark cluster on Mesos accessing HDFS data in a different Hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, mesos

We have a Hadoop cluster with datanodes 275 nodes (55Tb total memory , 12000 VCores). 
This cluster is shared  with couple of projects and we have a YARN queue assign to us with limited resources.

For enhanced performance, we are thinking about constructing a seperate Spark cluster for our project (on Mesos in the same network ) and access HDFS data on the Hadoop cluster.

As mentioned in Spark document :  https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#running-alongside-hadoop

My questions are :

1. Isn't this against the philosophy of Hadoop : "moving the computation to the data" ?
2. For optimal performance how much of nodes we will require for the new Spark cluster?

**--Edit--**

3. I want to know the how this data loading happens. For example, If I execute a SparkSQL query on a table , does it create RDDs in Mesos Spark cluster by loading data from Hadoop cluster, then do the processing on the generated RDDs ?
   Doesn't this cross cluster data IO impact the performance ? Since normally in YARN-Spark setup the RDDs and Data are in the same nodes.

Comment: Why not run HDFS in Mesos?

Comment: `Doesn't this cross cluster data IO impact the performance ?` - Yes. But you're still in the same network, as the answer below mentioned

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't this against the philosophy of Hadoop : "moving the computation to the data" ?

In general yes. Especially if these nodes are located in different data centers. The closer the better. Now, I read that they are in the same network:

> on Mesos in the same network

Measure the latency between the machines. Only then you can judge whether it's good or not.

> For optimal performance how much of nodes we will require for the new Spark cluster?

Optimal for who? It only depends on your use case.

> For example, If I execute a SparkSQL query on a table , does it create RDDs in Mesos Spark cluster by loading data from Hadoop cluster, then do the processing on the generated RDDs ?

Yes, although it's not a fixed process "read everything then process it" - it constantly reads, processes and then writes down the "partial results", because as you may guess, it can't load 1 TB of data in memory.

> Doesn't this cross cluster data IO impact the performance ? Since normally in YARN-Spark setup the RDDs and Data are in the same nodes.

Definitely! However, as I mentioned already, you should measure at least the latency between the nodes in this network if you want a more precise estimate - maybe some nodes are closer to the HDFS machines than others.

Without measurements (be it latency, performance tests, etc.) and a careful analysis of the network topology it's pure speculation.

Comment: modified the 3rd question